# How do I create ArrayList of Objects (string car model, int count, string percentage) in a loop?

Tags: java, object, for-loop, arraylist, hashmap

So I need to create Object for example called Car containing 
- String car model
- int count
- String percentage

After getting this data how do I put all Car Objects into for-loop of Objects to get Arraylist of all Car objects?

Comment: Add the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
List<Car> carList = new ArrayList();
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDesiredCars; i++){
   Car c = new Car(arguments);
   carList.add(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the question is?  Can you be a little more specific?  Are you saying you want all your objects into a list?  If so, you'd either add each one individually or you could do

```
        carList.addAll(Arrays.asList(carObject1, carObject2, and so on));
```

I don't know what you mean about put them all into a for loop after that.  What's the for loop being used for?  Are you just wanting to print all of them? If so, you wouldn't need a for loop to print the entire list, just if you wanted to print ones that meet only a certain criteria.

Comment: Don't answer if you don't fully understand the question, instead leave a comment to get further clarification.

Comment: It wouldn't let me leave a comment due to the reputation score.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide some code for us to help you directly, but to do what you say, it will be best to generally have two separate files.

In one file:

```
//Car.java
public class Car{
    private String model;  //instantaneous variables 
    private int count;
    private String percentage;

public Car(){   //default constructor
    model = "whateverModelName";
    count = 123;
    percentage = "75";
}

public Car(model,count,percentage){  //custom Constructor with parameters
}
```

Then in another file: CarRunner.java:

//carRunner.java

```
public class carRunner{
    public int numOfObjects = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Creates Car objects and initializes object name to "car1", "car2", etc.
        //Add code that adds 1 to numOfObjects each time an object is created
        getArrayList();  //calls getArrayList method


    }
    public static void getArrayList(){
    //creates and initializes your arrays to the proper sizes
    String[] model = new String[numOfObjects];
    String[] percentage = new String[numOfObjects];
    int[] count = new int[numOfObjects];

    for (i=1;i<=numOfObjects;i++){
        model[i] = car + i + .model;  //not sure how to do this actually, if someone can help write this to get the different variables from different objects

    }
    for (i=1;i<=numOfObjects;i++){
        percentage[i] = car + i + .percentage;  //not sure how to do this actually, if someone can help write this to get the different variables from different objects

    }
    for (i=1;i<=numOfObjects;i++){
        count[i] = car + i + .count;  //not sure how to do this actually, if someone can help write this to get the different variables from different objects

    }

}
```